# Add value from textbox to counter

Tags: javascript, html

I'm learning javascript and I want to create a simple clock. I want for user to be able to change minutes by entering a number in textbox and pressing a button, so when that number is displayed and when the seconds are counted to 60, that displayed number increase by 1, my code won't work, help pls:

```js
var seconds = 0;
var minutes2 = 0;
var rezultat;
let dugme = document.querySelector("#dugme");
var el = document.getElementById("seconds-counter");
var el2 = document.getElementById("minutes-counter");

function incrementSeconds() {
  seconds += 1;
  if (seconds === 60) {
    return seconds = 0;
  }
  el.innerText = seconds;
}
var cancel = setInterval(incrementSeconds, 1000);

dugme.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var minutes = parseInt(document.querySelector("#value").value);
  el2.innerText = minutes;
})

function incrementMinutes() {
  minutes2 += 1;
  if (minutes2 === 60) {
    return minutes2 = 0;
  }
  rezultat = (seconds + minutes2 + minutes);
  el2.innerText = rezultat;
}

var cancel = setInterval(incrementMinutes, 60000);
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="value">
  <button id="dugme" type="button">minuti</button>
</form>
<div id="seconds-counter"></div>
<div id="minutes-counter"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: you have 2 `</form>` why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few problems in your code. The main mistake is that your variable `minutes` is not defined in the function `incrementMinutes()` where you are trying to use it. You have to calculate it again.

Other improvements that you can make are:

- Remove the return in your `incrementSeconds` and `incrementMinutes` function
- Have only 1 `setInterval`, and call `incrementMinutes` when seconds reach 60.

You can see a snippet here below:

```js
var seconds = 0;
var minutes2 = 0;
var rezultat;
let dugme = document.querySelector("#dugme");
var el = document.getElementById("seconds-counter");
var el2 = document.getElementById("minutes-counter");

function incrementSeconds() {
  seconds += 1;
  if (seconds === 60) {
    seconds = 0;
    incrementMinutes();
  }
  el.innerText = seconds;
}
var cancel = setInterval(incrementSeconds, 1000);

dugme.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var minutes = parseInt(document.querySelector("#value").value);
  el2.innerText = minutes;
})

function incrementMinutes() {
  minutes2 += 1;
  if (minutes2 === 60) {
    minutes2 = 0;
  }
  rezultat = (minutes2 + parseInt(document.querySelector("#value").value));
  el2.innerText = rezultat;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="value">
  <button id="dugme" type="button">minuti</button>
</form>
<div id="seconds-counter"></div>
<div id="minutes-counter"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

To show here the behavior I made a minute to 5 seconds.

As a formatting improvement, if you want to show in result min:sec you can do this

```
min = min < 10 ? "0"+min : min;
seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
```

To build the string with leading zeros.

I have removed the returns because they were not neccessary you can inside reset the value there is no need to return it.

```js
var seconds = 0;
var min = 0;
var rezultat;
let dugme = document.querySelector("#dugme");
var secCounter = document.getElementById("seconds-counter");
var mintCounter = document.getElementById("minutes-counter");

function incrementSeconds() {
  seconds += 1;
  if (seconds === 60) {
      seconds = 0;
  }
  secCounter.innerText = seconds;
}
var cancel = setInterval(incrementSeconds, 1000);



function incrementMinutes() {
  min += 1;
  if (min === 60) {
      min = 0;
  }
  tempMin = min;
  tempSec = seconds;
  min = min < 10 ? "0"+min : min;
  seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
  rezultat = (min+":"+seconds);
  mintCounter.innerText = rezultat;
  min = tempMin;
  seconds = tempSec;
}

// for debugging to 5 sec
var cancel = setInterval(incrementMinutes, 5000);

dugme.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var inpMinutes = parseInt(document.querySelector("#value").value);
  min = inpMinutes;
  mintCounter.innerText = min;
})
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="value">
  <button id="dugme" type="button">minuti</button>
</form>
<div id="seconds-counter"></div>
<div id="minutes-counter"></div>
</form>
```